# Backup Destination full, Acronis BAAS

Tags: backup, acronis

I have a server where the versions were set too high on the backups. The drive became 100% full (0 bytes available space).

I lowered the versions and attempted to rerun the backup, however it appears that Acronis BAAS doesn't start with removal of old backups as it has still be failing. The job never starts and eventually just errors out.

If I attempt to delete old versions myself through the console, I cannot as selecting the "Recover" options loads forever. I believe this is because of having 0 bytes available space the drive cannot be read from even.

I know with some versions of Acronis manually deleting files off the drive messes everything up and the backup job has to be deleted and you need to create a new one.

Does anyone know if this is also the case with BAAS? What would be the best actions to take in this case to get backups going again? It has been 11 days now since the last backup, obviously if this goes on too long I'd just wipe the drive and start over, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: `What would be the best actions to take in this case to get backups going again? It has been 11 days now since the last backup` - Honestly, at what point do you consider contacting Acronis support? 11 days without a backup?

Comment: @joeqwerty I've contacted Acronis as well as Ingram Micro (who we purchased it through) they have just been going off topic the entire time without even answering my questions, just focusing on stuff like "What version do you have? You should install the newest update that came out yesterday..." which I feel is irrelevant to the problem. Which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Knowing what version you're running may well be relevant to the answers they're likely to give you. Updating to the latest version may also have a bearing on their answer. Additionally, both of those are stock responses from support. Did you push them beyond those two points in an attempt to get a solution for your problem?